# Member function pointer runtime error - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I've been searching for answers to this problem for the past hour but can't find a solution that works. I'm trying to use function pointers to call a non-static member function of a specific object. My code compiles fine, but during runtime I get a nasty runtime exception that says:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

A lot of websites said to specify the calling convention in the method header, so I added `__cdecl` before it. However, my code encountered the same runtime exception after the change (I tried using other calling conventions as well). I'm not sure why I have to specify cdecl in the first place because my project settings are set to cdecl. I am using some external libraries, but those were working fine before I added this function pointer stuff.

I'm following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/151449

My code:

**A.h**

```
#pragma once

class B;
typedef void (B::*ReceiverFunction)();

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    void addEventListener(ReceiverFunction receiverFunction);
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

A::A(){}
A::~A(){}
void A::addEventListener(ReceiverFunction receiverFunction)
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

**B.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    void testFunction();
    void setA(A* a);
    void addEvent();

private:
    A* a;

};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"

B::B(){}
B::~B(){}

void B::setA(A* a)
{
    this->a = a;
}
void B::addEvent()
{
    a->addEventListener(&B::testFunction); //This is the offending line for the runtime exception
}
void B::testFunction()
{
    //Nothing here
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    b->setA(a);
    b->addEvent();
}
```

I'm running with Visual Studio 2010, but I'd like my code to work on other platforms with minimal changes.

Comment: Of course your code is needed. But remember to give a minimal example.

Comment: watch out for the hidden argument (`this` pointer) in non-static method call

Comment: Compiler and platform, please.

Comment: Thanks guys - I've updated my post. @LeleDumbo: How should I use "this" with function pointers?

Comment: The code where you call the `receiverFunction`. Best provide a small snippet that exhibits the problem and is *complete*, i.e., can be copy-pasted for testing.

Comment: I don't call the receiverFunction method anywhere at the moment. I left the addEventListener method empty. I'll add the call code when the other stuff works.

Comment: Then what function call is the runtime issuing the error about?

Comment: Then your code looks [something like this](http://ideone.com/haP7m)?

Comment: I whipped up an example project and updated all of the code in my question. Same problem as before.

Comment: I get no error when running the provided code. :/ (I *did* put it all in one cpp file, but theoretically that shouldn't matter.) Maybe something is borked with your Visual Studio installation?

Comment: Could you send me the code you used? Also, are you running in Windows VS2010?

Comment: I just tried my code in Code::Blocks (which uses MinGW) and my code ran fine. What about Visual Studio could be causing this problem?

Comment: Oh my god, got the same error with the OP in VS 2010 ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c065ad7-a6cc-460a-8114-25b5ee01c76f/stack-corruption-when-passing-pointer-to-member-function-of-a-forward-referenced-class), necessary ingredients are a member pointer declaration using an incomplete class and having it used in different translation units.  An optimization in the MSVC compiler, it uses different internal representations for a member pointers depending on the inheritance.

The workaround is to compile with `/vmg` or to [declare the inheritance explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck561bfk.aspx):

```
class __single_inheritance B;
typedef void (B::*ReceiverFunction)();
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c065ad7-a6cc-460a-8114-25b5ee01c76f/stack-corruption-when-passing-pointer-to-member-function-of-a-forward-referenced-class
seems to be the currently working link of the first URL.

Comment: The Connect web site is discontinued with no Wayback Machine backup of their articles.  Doesn't matter, focus on the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Seems not many has reproduced the problem, I'll first show the behavior of VS2010 on this piece of code here. (DEBUG build, 32bit OS)

The problem is in `B::addEven()` and `A::addEventListener()`. To give me a reference point to check the `ESP` value, two additional statements are added to `B::addEven()`.

```
// in B.cpp, where B is complete
void B::addEvent()
{
00411580  push        ebp  
00411581  mov         ebp,esp  
00411583  sub         esp,0D8h  
00411589  push        ebx  
0041158A  push        esi  
0041158B  push        edi  
0041158C  push        ecx  
0041158D  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]  
00411593  mov         ecx,36h  
00411598  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
0041159D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
0041159F  pop         ecx  
004115A0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
    int i = sizeof(ReceiverFunction); // added, sizeof(ReceiverFunction) is 4
004115A3  mov         dword ptr [i],4  
    a->addEventListener(&B::testFunction); //This is the offending line for the runtime exception
004115AA  push        offset B::testFunction (411041h)  
004115AF  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
004115B2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
004115B4  call        A::addEventListener (4111D6h)  
    i = 5;            // added
004115B9  mov         dword ptr [i],5  
}
004115C0  pop         edi  
004115C1  pop         esi  
004115C2  pop         ebx  
004115C3  add         esp,0D8h  
004115C9  cmp         ebp,esp  
004115CB  call        @ILT+330(__RTC_CheckEsp) (41114Fh)  
004115D0  mov         esp,ebp  
004115D2  pop         ebp  
004115D3  ret  

// In A.cpp, where B is not complete
void A::addEventListener(ReceiverFunction receiverFunction)
{
00411470  push        ebp  
00411471  mov         ebp,esp  
00411473  sub         esp,0D8h  
00411479  push        ebx  
0041147A  push        esi  
0041147B  push        edi  
0041147C  push        ecx  
0041147D  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]  
00411483  mov         ecx,36h  
00411488  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
0041148D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
0041148F  pop         ecx  
00411490  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
    int i = sizeof(receiverFunction);  // added, sizeof(receiverFunction) is 10h
00411493  mov         dword ptr [i],10h  
    //Do nothing
}
0041149A  pop         edi  
0041149B  pop         esi  
0041149C  pop         ebx  
0041149D  mov         esp,ebp  
0041149F  pop         ebp  
004114A0  ret         10h
```

`A:: addEventListener()` used `ret 10h` to clear the stack, but only 4 bytes are pushed into the stack (`push offset B::testFunction`), which cause the stack frame to be corrupted.

Seem that depending whether `B` is complete or not, `sizeof(void B::*func())` would change in VS2010. In OP's code, in A.cpp `B` is not complete, and the size is `10h`. In call site B.cpp, when `B` is already complete, the size becomes `04h`. (This can be checked by `sizeof(ReceiverFunction)` as shown in the above code). This caused that in the call site, and in the actual code of `A::addEventListener()`, the size of the augment/parameter are not the same, thus caused stack corruption.

I changed the order of inclusion to make sure `B` is complete in every translation unit, and the runtime error disappears.

This should be a VS2010 bug ...

---

Compiler Command Line:

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\test.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

Linker Command Line:

```
/OUT:"...\test.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\test.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"...\test.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"...\test.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

I hid some pathes in the command line.

Comment: Ahh, this actually sounds plausible. Depending on the inheritance and virtual-ness of any functions, the type of member-function-pointer is actually more or less complicated. You can read about it in the source code of [this delegate implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx). It's arcane.

Comment: @Xeo: I've heard of this. I also wonder whether the code is well formed according to the specification.

Comment: @fefe: This still seems to be a bug, because VS should stick to one member-function-pointer type.

Comment: VS has options for selecting best or worst case member function pointer sizes for incomplete types. The size varies a lot depending on potential virtual inheritance and such things.

Comment: @SimonRichter: I used the default, seems to be /W3. Will add the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Using /vmg as a compiler option fixed the problem.

However, I decided to use a delegate library instead (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ImpossiblyFastCppDelegate.aspx), and it works well!