# Can I use member function as first argument to EnumWindows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Can I use member function as first argument to `EnumWindows`? I don't see any workaround in this case even with `boost::bind`.

Comment: Or you can make your own `bind` function (with right calling convention) using `lParam` to pass it a pointer to member function...

Comment: @hmjd Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @FrozenHeart, you should be able to use a lambda (I don't have access to a VS compiler at the moment).

Comment: @hmjd Capturing lambdas cannot be converted to free functions.

Comment: @hmjd It's clear that capturing lambdas cannot be converted to free functions because how would it know where to get its captured variables from?

Comment: @RaymondChen: trampoline. But that might be hard on exotic hardware.

Comment: @MSalters C++ has no provision for dynamic code generation. (Harvard architecture does not support it, for example. NX for another.) C++ is based on the principle that all code generation occurs at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this *normal* callback function:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam);
```

You can invoke `EnumWindows` using `lParam` to pass it a pointer to your class:

```
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
```

In `EnumWindowsProc` you can simply call member function (casting `lParam` to your class type). Like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(lParam)->EnumWindows(wnd);
}
```

If you don't want to make your class method public you can:

- Pack a struct to contain both class instance and pointer to member.
- Use a library for *delegates*.
- Use boost `std:bind` (in this case it'll work well because you do it on your own class member, it has not to be `__stdcall`).

Whatever you will use you can find more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151418/calling-a-c-function-pointer-on-a-specific-object-instance) here on SO.

Comment: You are correct, I take back what I said.

Comment: Your compiler allow static_cast for 'this' to LPARAM?

Comment: @manuell pretty right, fixed...price to pay for uncompiled snippets wrote here!

Comment: @Adriano I really would like to see the code for the std::bind case (bonus, it's in the OP question)

Comment: @manuell just look John's answer (or link in my answer to another SO post). It's little bit too prolix but more or less it's that.

Comment: @Adriano That's using the LPARAM... Sigh... I hoped for some magic. Never mind.

Comment: @manuell yes, AFAIK no magic

Answer (score 3):

EnumWindows takes a callback that looks like this

`BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam);`

You cannot use either a member function or a lambda that has a capture. You do this instead.

```
typedef std::function<bool(HWND hwnd)> func_type;
BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lparam)
{
    auto& func = *reinterpret_cast<func_type*>(lparam);
    if(func(hwnd))return TRUE;
    else return FALSE;

}
```

You would use it like this

```
auto f = std::make_shared<func_type>(std::bind(&mymemberfunction,this));
EnumWindows(MyEnumProc,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(f.get()));

//Make sure to keep the shared_ptr around until you are done enumerating
```