# A vector member is reset and unaccessible

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, forward-declaration

I have two projects, one basic client and a dynamic library.
Here's what happens in the client:

```
int main()
{
    Scrutinizer scru;
    scru.Scrutinize();
    return 0;
}
```

In the DLL, The `Scrutinizer` class is as such *(__declspec(dllexport) and such omitted for Clarity)*

**Header**

```
class ProcessesGenerator;

    class Scrutinizer
    {
    public:
    Scrutinizer();
    ~Scrutinizer();
    ProcessesGenerator *ProcGenerator
    void Scrutinize();
};
```

The forward declaration of `ProcessesGenerator` was 'mandatory' for me to avoid some kind of circular reference.

**Constructor in .cpp file**

Here is how I initialize it:

```
Scrutinizer::Scrutinizer()
{
    ProcGenerator = &ProcessesGenerator();
}
```

More about this `ProcessesGenerator` class:

**Header**

```
class ProcessesGenerator
{

public:
    ProcessesGenerator();
    ~ProcessesGenerator();
    WinFinder winFinder;
    std::vector<std::string> fooCollec;

    void GenerateProcesses();
};
```

**ProcessesGenerator.cpp**

Constructor:

```
ProcessesGenerator::ProcessesGenerator()
{
    //winFinder = WinFinder();//problem will be the same with or without this line
    fooCollec = std::vector<std::string>{"one", "two", "three"};
}
```

A breakpoint in the constructor shows that the vector is initialized with the chosen values.

Problematic function:

```
void ProcessesGenerator::GenerateProcesses() {
    std::string foo = "bar";
    fooCollec = std::vector<std::string>{};//read access violation
    fooCollec.push_back(foo);//read access violation
    winFinder.SomeVector= std::vector<std::string>{};//read access violation
}
```

Once there, I Can see that the size of vector is reset to 0. Any attempt to re-initialize it, or to push an element results in read access violation .Same with the vecotr member of its `WinFinder` member. I guess the flaw is obvious, but I really don't get it,

Thanks!

Comment: What compiler are you using?  `ProcGenerator = &ProcessesGenerator();` should not compile.

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2017 under Windows 10, and get it to compile with 'Build' function or by clicking 'Local Windows Debugger'

Comment: @NathanOliver that's well known pesky MS feature - temp to lvalue implicit conversion

Comment: @Slava That's just criminal.  It's as bad as them binding temporaries to non const references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with

```
Scrutinizer::Scrutinizer()
{
    ProcGenerator = &ProcessesGenerator();
}
```

What you are doing is taking the address of a temporary object.  That object will be destroyed and the end of that line and you will be left with a pointer that doesn't point to a valid object.

The old way to fix it would be to use

```
Scrutinizer::Scrutinizer()
{
    ProcGenerator = new ProcessesGenerator();
}
```

But now you have to implement the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and the destructor.  Since you have a modern compiler what you can do instead is make `ProcGenerator` a `std:unique_ptr<ProcessesGenerator>` and then `Scrutinizer()` becomes

```
Scrutinizer::Scrutinizer() : ProcGenerator(make_unique<ProcessesGenerator>()) {}
```

---

I would also like to add that `&ProcessesGenerator();` should not even compile.  Unfortunately MSVS has a non-standard extension that allows this to compile.  You can turn on the `/Za` compiler option (enforce ANSI compatibility) and then you should get an error like

> error C2102: '&' requires l-value

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help and teach! It worked on a minimal project, but my actual project showed me the weird errors that had me using a forward declaration in the first place. I couldn't fix it after hours, so I got away by not making it a member of the class and creating a new instance when needed. I guess goinig from C# to C++ does not happens so quickly… THANKS anyway

Answer (score 1):

The line `ProcGenerator = &ProcessesGenerator();` makes a temporary `ProcessesGenerator`, takes its address and then puts it in your `ProcGenerator` pointer. The temporary is then destroyed, leaving garbage.

You probably wanted to be allocating it on the heap `ProcGenerator = new ProcessesGenerator;` but even in that case I would strongly suggest using `unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.