# Methode to call function with pointer in vector

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I try to call some functions stacked in vector.  I did:

```
DataReader* GPSR_Ptr = new DataReader();
typedef leap::float64 (DataReader::*getFonction)();
std::vector<getFonction> vec (&DataReader::getLat);
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify `But that didn't work`?

Comment: `std::vector<getFonction> vec(1, &DataReader::getLat);`

Comment: is `DataReader::getLat` static?

Comment: No, DataReader is not a static function

Comment: then you need an [instance of `DataReader` in order to call this function using the function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151418/calling-a-c-function-pointer-on-a-specific-object-instance)

Comment: DON'T put code in comments, update your question please!

Answer (score 3):

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has no constructor taking a single value. Use an initializer list :

```
std::vector<getFonction> vec {&DataReader::getLat};
```

If you are stuck in 2003, you can also use the filling constructor :

```
std::vector<getFonction> vec(1, &DataReader::getLat);
```

But beware that it will copy the parameter, which you may not want for other types.