# Vector containing function of a class

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently trying to create a vector containing function of a class .

***Here is my code :***

```
typedef leap::float64 (DataReader::*getFonction)();

std::vector<getFonction> vec;
std::vector<getFonction>::iterator it;

vec.push_back(&DataReader::getLa);
vec.push_back(&DataReader::getLon);

for(it = vec.begin(); it<vec.end(); it++)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

The function "get ..." (not static ) returned values ​​are stored on shared resources and already initialized.
But then , they return me only the values ​​'1'.

An idea?

Comment: What do you expect to be output when you try to print a function pointer? It is implicitly being converted to `bool`.

Comment: You should rather use `std::function` as vector items.

Comment: You need an instance to call member function pointer using `.*` or `->*`

Comment: You need to call the function.  dereferencing the iterator is just going to give you a pointer value

Comment: And to second @NathanOliver: For calling the function you'll need to have a valid `DataReader` instance.

Comment: Should we crosslink this question with [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31988571/3233393) or something ?

Comment: @Quentin I knew I've seen it before today. The `getFonction` is very suspect. Hopefully the OP isn't using a sock puppet to probe their questions acceptance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's a follow-up question that other-side OP mistakenly posted as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31988957/3233393). No clue what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you dereference `it` and output it, you are just printing out a representation of the function pointer, which is being implicitly converted to `bool` and output as `1` because it is not null.

If you want to call the function and output the return value, you need to call it on an instance:

```
DataReader reader;

for(it = vec.begin(); it<vec.end(); it++)
    //dereference it to get member function pointer and call it on reader
    std::cout << (reader.*(*it))() << std::endl;
```

If you are using C++11, `std::function` may be better suited:

```
using getFunction = std::function<leap::float64(DataReader&)>;

std::vector<getFunction> vec;
std::vector<getFunction>::iterator it;

vec.emplace_back(&DataReader::getLa);
vec.emplace_back(&DataReader::getLon);

DataReader reader;
for(it = vec.begin(); it<vec.end(); it++)
    std::cout << (*it)(reader) << std::endl;
```